# Using relational database rollback for ensuring atomicity when using external web service

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, relational-database

Our backend (PHP) accepts some data from the user and than creates a resource in external web service and saves this user data in relational database (MySQL), as well as id of newly created resource. What is the best way to ensure atomicity of the whole operation (with database rollbacks, for example)? Will this scheme work:

1. Get user data from the request, perform server side validation, if it fails, return 400 status
2. If validation is ok, save user data to database, but do not close transaction.
3. Perform a request to external web service.
4. If it fails, rollback the transaction, and return 400 status code.
5. If it succeeds, close transaction.

At which point will database constraints violations will be reported? At step 2 or step 5?

P.S: I'm not a backend developer, so please excuse for the newbie question.

Comment: Why can't you just do the external web request first, and then only write to the db if it succeeds?

Comment: To avoid situation, when external resource is created, but saving user data and resource id to database fails (due to constraint validations failure, for example)

Comment: I don't think keeping the transaction open ensures atomicity. Maybe have another column with a bool flag indicating that user record is unavailable until the external web request comes back successful. Problem is you have to check that from everywhere else in your code...

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. Do you need atomicity because of the rollback? If so you could lock the whole table in sql, I think.